# Authentication using Passport JS for facebook

Tags: node.js, facebook, oauth, passport.js

The redirection to facebook.com doesn't happen once I click on below link:

```
<a href="/auth/facebook" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-facebook">&nbsp; Facebook</span> </a>
```

Routes are as follows:

```
//Facebook
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope : ['email'] }));

app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { successRedirect: '/profile',
                                      failureRedirect: '/' }));
```

The Strategy code is as follows:

```
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: configAuth.facebookAuth.clientID,
        clientSecret: configAuth.facebookAuth.clientsecret,
        profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'email'],
        callbackURL: configAuth.facebookAuth.callbackURL
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        process.nextTick(function() {
            User.findOne({
                'facebook.id': profile.id
            }, function(err, user) {
                if (err)
                    return done(err);
                if (user)
                    return done(null, user);
                else {
                    var newUser = new User();
                    newUser.facebook.id = profile.id;
                    newUser.facebook.token = accessToken;
                    newUser.facebook.name = profile.name.givenName + ' ' + profile.name.familyName;
                    newUser.facebook.email = profile.email[0].value;

                    newUser.save(function(err) {
                        if (err)
                            throw err;
                        else
                            return done(null, newUser);
                    })
                }
            });
        });

    }
));
```

I have update the secrets in my auth.js file.
I have also updated the Website URL: http://localhost:8080 and added appdomain : localhost in developers.facebook.com

Whenever I click on the HTML link the control remains on same page and then the webpage http://localhost:8080/auth/facebook cannot be found is displayed

Answer (score 0):

You should update the website url in facebook developers as `http://localhost:8080/auth/facebook/callback`. As far as i see there is nothing wrong in your code. I too have created this application the only difference between your code and my code is that i used ssl certificates. Even if the updated url doesnot work for you, let me know.

Comment: Thanks @Gousia for replying.
But I guess [http://localhost:8080/] should be the site URL.
And [http://localhost:8080/auth/facebook/callback] should be the Callback URL.

Although I changed it, as you suggested still no success.

The problem is once I click on FB Link, the page just loads and then times out after few seconds saying http://localhost:8080/auth/facebook/ could not be connected

Comment: Try by adding the ssl certificates, i think it would work